# Insert array data into SQL Server from local sqlite database using json and restful

Tags: java, android, sql-server, json

How to insert array data into SQL Server from local sqlite database using json and restful? Please any tell me that idea...

```
public static class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    public void sendDataToServer(){


    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: how to connect android to server via json ?

Comment: You can write a REST/SOAP api to get/post the data from your server to the app or vice versa.

Comment: i have that API

Comment: So what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to store `JSONObject` or Model class `object` into local database.

```
// This is for get data from database.
Gson gson = new Gson();
String strDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column name"));
Customer customer = gson.fromJson(strDate , Customer.class);
```

In `customer` you will get object and then you can send this object to sql server.

Comment: into server????

Comment: Wait let me update my ans.

Comment: sry..., how to send that ?

Comment: For that you need API for it do you have API?

Comment: i am new in android ... API means?

Comment: API means you need web-services where you can insert data in to sql-server from your mobile app.